# How to synchronize a Filter DE based of a Synchronized DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization, marketingcloudapi

I have created a filter from a synchronized DE.

I would like this filter DE to be automatically synchronized when new data gets added or removed.

**Issues**

When trying to create an automation > activity type > SQL Query, hence the type of the DE is "Filter" it does not show in the list to assign a query to the DE.

When trying to create an automation > activity type > Filter, it's only allowing me to select DEs from the "Data Filters" folder.

**Current process**

Currently, to achieve this task, Instead of creating a filtered DE, I create a standard DE, and link a Query to it and drop it in automation. I don't like this process because to duplicate the syncronized DE to a standard DE, I make an API call to fetch all the fields from the Synchronized DE and then I use another API call to post the new DE with all the fields.

Where for creating a filter from a synchronized DE, the new "Filtered DE" gets created with all the new fields automatically.

**Key goal**

Is there a way to make a filtered DE, based on a synchronized Data Extension, synchronized? Or perhaps a better way to create duplicate DE from a Synchronized DE without having to manually type in all the fields or to use an API to do so?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

There is a possibility of automating a Data Filter in Automation Studio ([Automatically refresh a Filtered Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320525&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)), but it won’t work with a Synched DE.

On top of that, if you try creating a filtered Data Extension from a Synchronized Data Extension, you might find yourself experiencing the documented bug:

> Filtered Data Extensions created from Synchronized data extensions
>   fail when using 2 or more fields in filter

You can read more here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmiYQAS&title=filtered-data-extensions-created-from-synchronized-data-extensions-fail-when-using-2-or-more-fields-in-filter

Currently, the easier workaround is to use **SQL query** instead of a filter.

If you need the functionality of using drag and drop to segment data, without the need to use SQL, you can look into Audience Builder, but this will be paid extra: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ab_audience_builder.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

If you know how to use SSJS, you could write a script that will utilize the undocumented REST API endpoint that will refresh your filtered DE. You can also automate it. Read more here: https://gortonington.com/refresh-a-filtered-data-extension-via-rest-api/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I only need to filter using one field. But the article "Automatically refresh a Filtered Data Extension" that you shared demonstrates how to create a data filter from a standard data extension. The folder "Synchronized Data Extension" is not accessible to me to create the data filter from a synchronized DE.

Comment: You’re right, I have updated my answer.